# Horizontal scroll in fixed column DataTables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 and DataTables.

I'm having problems when I try to fix columns, each fixed column adds a horizontal scroll

This is my code

```js
var table = $('#tabla').DataTable({
  //scrollY: "300px",
  scrollX: true,
  paging: false,
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 1,
    rightColumns: 1
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

<table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código Delfos</th>
            <th>Nota de Venta</th>
            <th>Primer Cliente</th>
            <th>Norma</th>
            <th>Potencia</th>
            <th>Tensión Mayor</th>
            <th>Tensión Menor</th>
            <th>Material de arrollamiento mayor</th>
            <th>Material de arrollamiento menor</th>
            <th>Frecuencia</th>
            <th>Grupo de Conexiones</th>
            <th>Regulación</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     
            <tr>
                <td>07-F0CAAEUAFEJ0000B0001</td>
                <td>11756</td>
                <td>DIR.PROV.ENERGIA DE CORRIENTES</td>
                <td>IRAM 2476</td>
                <td>630,00</td>
                <td>33.000</td>
                <td>13.860</td>
                <td>datos</td>
                <td>datos</td>
                <td>datos</td>
                <td>datos</td>
                <td>33000,00( + 5x5,0000% ; - 5x5,00%)</td>
            </tr>
       

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see the table got totally bugged because of that both scrolls (first and last columns) and you can also see that by moving the scroll, you can see the contents of the back cells.

What i'm doing wrong?

I based my code on DataTables Fixed Column for Bootstrap 4

Thanks so much, and sory for my horrible english

Comment: I see you have scrollX set to true. What do you want to scroll?

Comment: @chaggy i have it because the table will get some like 30 columns, and the idea is to fix both first and last column, and horizontally scroll the other columns

Comment: try and remove the 'overflow-y: scroll;` on that element

Comment: @chaggy i tried but nothing change :S, but i noted, when i remove Bootstrap `table-bordered` class, everything fits perfectly

Comment: @chaggy the post that you deleted was the solution! why u delete it? :P

Comment: I hit delete instead of edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a hack but you can try,

```
<style>
    .DTFC_LeftBodyLiner{overflow-y:unset !important}
    .DTFC_RightBodyLiner{overflow-y:unset !important}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it's exactly what i need!

Comment: I see no borders on left and rifgt after this. Anyway it works. Still, searching for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [BackpackforLaravel](https://Backpackforlaravel.com) bundle, so need only change configuration in `config/backpack/crud.php`:

```
'responsive_table' => false,
```